# Simple question: how to add text to r chunk in rmd format?

Tags: r

I have this code outside of a chunk. This gives me and html output of the number of participants, number of male participants, number of female, and other in a neat html output.

```
`r length(Participant_Overview_Sequential$participant_id)` participants
`r length(which(Participant_Overview_Sequential$SEX == "1"))` male, 
`r length(which(Participant_Overview_Sequential$SEX == "2"))` female,
`r length(which(Participant_Overview_Sequential$SEX == "3"))` other
```

I've been trying to put this inside of an r chunk in rmd format, so this would be done by removing the backticks but I can't get the html output to be the same because I dont know how to add the text and the output of the numbers comes with a [1].

I would basically like to know how to get the same html output by putting that into a chunk!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting the same output in-line and from a chunk. Probably not the most efficient coding but proves the concept.

```
---
title: "code inline and in chunk"
output: html_document
---
```

**in-line**

```
`r length(mtcars$gear)` participants  
`r length(which(mtcars$gear == 3))` male,   
`r length(which(mtcars$gear == 4))` female,  
`r length(which(mtcars$gear == 5))` other
```

**in chunk**

````
```{r, results='asis'}

cat(paste(length(mtcars$gear), "participants  \n"))
cat(paste(length(which(mtcars$gear == 3)), "male,  \n"))
cat(paste(length(which(mtcars$gear == 4)), "female,  \n"))
cat(paste(length(which(mtcars$gear == 5)), "other  \n"))

```
````

[Link to image of rmarkdown html output](https://rpubs.com/peter-m/790516)